# Single Pointer pointing to two different struct tables

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, declaration, typedef

I have already read the article below, but I still have the same question.....

If I have a void pointer that I cast at the runtime to one or to other structures, what seems to be the problem here ? For example a pseudo code like below

```
typedef struct A {

   int x;
   int y;

} A1;

typedef struct B {

  int x;
  int y;

} B1;


.......

A1 *a1;
B1 *b1;
void *prt;

a1 = new A1;
b1 = new B1;

prt = reinterpret_cast<A1>(a1); // ptr shows to a1 structure ?
prt = reinterpret_cast<B1>(b1); // ptr shows to b1 structure ?
```

Will ptr points to a1 and b1 structures ?

[[Single Pointer pointing to two different const struct table(look up tables) in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470528/single-pointer-pointing-to-two-different-const-struct-tablelook-up-tables-in-c])

Comment: C has no `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: there are many errors in your code, which you should know if you tried to compile it. For starters there are no variables named `A1` or `B1`. To continue your casts will not work, not even if you change the meaning of `A1` and `B1`, because then you would be casting a pointer to a non-pointer and assign it to a pointer. And of course, no matter what you do the code will never compile as C code, because it's C++ code.

Comment: Define "work". What do you mean by your question?

Comment: `A1` and `B1` is (defined type) type, not a variable.

Comment: However, a void pointer (i.e. `void*`) is a generic pointer, and can point to anything that can be pointed to. But a word of warning: Don't use it! It will make your code needlessly complex and hard to read and understand. If you want to point to specific structure, then have a pointer to that structure, not a generic pointer.

Comment: Just don't do stuff like this. Also don't use `typedef struct`, C++ has proper way of defining classes.

Comment: Don't care if its c or c++ code. I just need one variable to have access to different structures and change this at the runtime. Is that possible ? For example, I am reading x bytes from a file, if it is version 1 use structure A, if version 2 use structure 2 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction

```
typedef struct A {

   int x;
   int y;

} *A1;
```

defines a new typedef name. It is not a declaration of an object with name A1. So it would be more correctly to write

```
struct A {

   int x;
   int y;

} *A1;
```

if you want that A1 would be an object.

Also you may assign a pointer of any type to a pointer of void. So you could write simply

```
prt = A1;
prt = B1;
```

instead of this invalid code

```
prt = reinterpret_cast<A>(A1); 
prt = reinterpret_cast<B>(B1);
```

There is no problem with these

```
prt = A1;
prt = B1;
```

assignments.

If you want to access data members of two different structures using one pointer then you can not do this because these two structures have different types and the pointer can have only one type.

You could do what you want if you woud define a union of these two structures.

Or if you mean the following

```
#include <iostream> 

int main () 
{
    struct A
    {
        int x, y;
    } a;

    struct B
    {
        int x, y;
    } b;

    void *p = &a;

    reinterpret_cast<A *>( p )->x = 10;
    reinterpret_cast<A *>( p )->y = 20;

    p = &b;

    reinterpret_cast<B *>( p )->x = 30;
    reinterpret_cast<B *>( p )->y = 40;

    std::cout << "a: " << a.x << '\t' << a.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << b.x << '\t' << b.y << std::endl;

    return 0; 
 }
```

then there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks, don't brother with the declarations, the point here is to use just one variable to access members of different structures. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Maverick In this case you should use the reverse casting from type void * to a pointer of the selected structure.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, that's what I was looking for, with one exception. I would prefer to use the reinterpret_cast only the first time I assign the address of the structure to the pointer p, for example something like reinterpret_cast<A*>( p ) = &a; and then using p to access the data members directly without using again and again the reinterpret_cast like p->x = 30; Is that possible ?. Generally my idea at the very beggining is using different structures  for reading file headers and save those info to a mem structure... Can you suggest something better ?

Comment: @Maverick You may not use pointer p without reinterpret_cast each time when you want to access data members of the structure because the type of the pointer is void *. Or you should use one more pointer that will store the reinterpreted value of p.